# Secure connection between Kubernetes nodes

Tags: security, kubernetes

We have an HA Kubernetes cluster. We want to secure the connection between nodes with TLS, but I don't want to secure the connection between pods in a node, is that anyway?

Comment: you want to use TLS for communication between pods across different nodes but not on same node?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes I want that

Comment: I think this can be done using Weave, but I' not 100% sure.